# Python PuLP: Keep variables relative to each other

Tags: python, pulp

I want to minimize x1+x2+x3 with PuLP, which works fine already. However the result often consists of one of the three being zero and just the other two ones being used by the algorithm. Is there a way to keep them relative to each other? They all three have the same cost.

For example, instead of PuLP solving the equation with 4+0+5 it should be something like 3+3+3. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to achieve sort of what I wanted by looping the calculation while incrementing a threshhold for the variables:

```
x <= threshhold
y <= threshhold
z <= threshhold
```

It means sacrificing some computing power but for my case it isn't really that much more time and serves the job.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of the simplex algorithm will always find extreme point solutions i.e

```
max x+y+z

x+y+z <=1

x,y,z >= 0
```

The solutions returned will always be

```
x=1 y=0 z=0
```

or

```
x=0, y=1, z=0
```

or

```
x=0, y=0, z=1
```

With a Linear formulation it is actually difficult to force an interior point solution

```
x=1/3, y=1/3, z=1/3
```

you may need to add a non-linear objective function to get this to work and pulp can't model that :-(

Comment: I don't need/want interior point solutions. The solution should always be whole integer numbers, hence I used a linear approach with PuLP. For my specific purpose I know for a fact that the x+y+z will always be big enough for these three to add up roughly evenly. I just don't know how to get them evenly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a penalty to the objective function.

The penalty would be the sum of all absolute differences between the variables.

First, you need to define variables that correspond to the absolute differences :

`delta1 = x - y`

`delta2 = x - z`

`delta3 = x - y`

Then you need to convert the deltas to a sum a difference of two positive integers, so that you can then minimize the absolute value
(cf https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/114/how-to-minimize-an-absolute-value-in-the-objective-of-an-lp)

```
delta1 = pos_delta1 - neg_delta1, 
delta1 = ...
```

with pos_delta1 >= 0, and neg_delta1 >=0.

Than add the minimization of pos_delta1 + neg_delta1 to the objective

`minimize x + y + z + pos_delta1 + neg_delta1 + pos_delta2 + ...`